How to create a ASP.net core project and host it on a Apache based web server without a reverse proxy?
I want to host my Web App on a Apache server I've tried to publish a self contained project and would upload to the server but that does not work, I tired to compile it using Linux it the output setting in visual studio but that didn't also work.
I read that you have to setup your apache server as a reverse proxy but I haven't got the ability to do that as it's a shared server.
I would be able to host it? how would the set up be as I've tried multiple things but can't get it to work
Not sure if this matters but this is the server settings
Server OS   Proprietary *nix
Server hardware Cloud-based server instance
Web server  Apache
I'm lost on how this will all work, all the documentation i see is just about using it as a reverse proxy which I can't do is there a way around or a better way to do it?

The only way to run ASP.NET Core applications with Apache is with mod_proxy - there is no Apache module for running ASP.NET Core in-proc (at least according to a quick google search I did just now). However, being on a shared-host does not mean you can't use mod_proxy - I suggest you speak to your hosting provider and ask them if mod_proxy is already enabled, and if not, if they can enable it for your account.

"Server OS Proprietary *nix Server" <-- The only "proprietary *nix OSes that are still around would be macOS, SCO OpenServer+UnixWare, and uh... that's it - and none of those platforms run .NET (because they aren't Linux), sooo please clarify.

that is just listed on the server settings

If i do have access how would I do it?

It sounds like you're using something like cPanel or Plesk?

yeah it's cPanel

This is possible just using Kestrel, which comes built-in with ASP.NET Core. All you really need to do is use Systemd to configure the app as a service, change the port it listens on in the .service file, and then open the ports.
You're on a proprietary distro of Linux, so I'm not sure these commands will be the same. This is what I used for Ubuntu.

Create a Systemd configuration file. Example, /var/systemd/system/Test.service
Add the following to that file. Be sure to change the project settings wherever you see "Test" and change the IP addresses on the Environment variable.

    [Unit]
    Description=Test
    [Service]
    WorkingDirectory=/var/Test
    ExecStart=/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet /var/Test/bin/Release/net8.0/Test.dll
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=10
    SyslogIdentifier=Test
    #User=www-data
    Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://10.100.10.50:5000;https://10.100.10.50:5001
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target


Run systemctl daemon-reload and then run systemctl start Test
If you want the service to start on reboot run systemctl enable Test
If your firewall is enabled, allow ports 5000 & 5001

You should be able to access the server on port 5000 now.
[EDIT] I just realized that you may not know how to publish the app before configuring all of this. Follow these steps to publish the app first. This is assuming you've already installed .Net by using sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-8.0

Create a directory like /var/Test (mkdir /var/Test)
cd /var/Test
I'll just create a new app for this example, so run the following to create a new .Net app dotnet new web. You can always copy your project files here later on.
dotnet build
dotnet publish -c Release

That will get your site published to the server, so you can now run the steps above. By default, .Net 8.0 apps run on port 5000 for HTTP, and port 5001 for HTTPS.

this might not me possible as it's shared hosting but will give it a go
